# Notepad++ regex to capitalise the first word of selected sentence

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds

*Relates to customising Notepad++. I know TextFX 'Sentence case.' exists but I wanted to control this using my own regex/macro.*

Testing against: `hello my name is john. hello my name is john. hello my name is john.`

Currently I have this which works fine when nothing is selected/highlighted with the mouse.

```
Find what:    ((?<=^|(?<=[.!?]\s)))(\w)
Replace with: \u$0
```

However, when I select/highlight the second (middle) sentence only (starting at the `h` and finishing on the period `.`), the regex does nothing. **Note: I have 'Use selection' ticked in N++ and am using 'Replace All'.**

This makes sense because the regex is looking for the start of a line or the char pattern `.!?` followed by a space.

My question is how to alter the regex so that it works when selecting/highlighting any sentence, no matter if it isn't at the beginning of a line as per my example.

I have tried adding in a negative lookbehind to match when no characters are found but I only managed to uppercase the first word of every sentence.

Comment: You know, it works when you press *Replace All*, there is an issue with *Replace*.

Comment: Yes - if the text is unhighlighted the regex I provided works fine but I want to be able to highlight a sentence and convert only that sentence to sentence case. I therefore need to extend the regex to cover this scenario which is my aim by asking this question.

Comment: Try `(^|[.!?]\s+)(\w)` --> `$1\u$2`

Comment: Thanks but this does not work when, for example, just the middle sentence is highlighted. This works like the regex I have provided when nothing is highlighted.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I tried to follow the same scenario, and `(\A|[.!?]\s+)(\w+)` --> `$1\u$2` looks to work.

Comment: Aha replacing `^` with `\A` was the key! Expanded yours to be `(?<=\A|(?<=[.!?]\s))(\w+)` --> `\u$0`. Submit an answer and I will approve? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^` matches the start of a line, while your selected region is not at the line start. You may replace it with `\A`, the [*start of the matching string*](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions). Since it will match at each selected region, you cannot use `\w`, you need to add `+` after it so as not to turn each subsequent word char to upper case.

Use

```
(?<=\A|(?<=[.!?]\s))(\w+)
```

and replace with `\u$0`.

[image]

Alternative way is to use capturing groups (then, you will be able to match cases where the number of whitespaces between `!`, `?` or `.` and the next word char is more than one):

```
(\A|[.!?]\s+)(\w+)
```

to replace with `$1\u$2`.